# Shouldn't shallow copy create an object with different id in python?

Tags: python, list, shallow-copy

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 =list1
id(list1[0]) == id(list2[0])  #True
id(list1) == id(list2)        #True
```

I am trying to learn the concept of deep copy and shallow copy. I understand that list1  and list2 would be references to the same memory, therefore id(list1[0]) will be equal to id(list2[0]). But shouldn't id(list1) be different from id(list2) as both are different objects of class list.

Comment: "But shouldn't id(list1) be different from id(list2) as both are different objects of class list." - but they're not. You didn't make two list objects.

Comment: ```list2 =list1``` point to the same list in the same memory location

Comment: `list2=list1` does not make a shallow copy of the *list*. It makes a copy of the *reference* to the list.

Comment: As correctly stated earlier, list2=list1 is merely copying a reference (a.k.a. pointer) to list1 to a new variable list2. If you want a shallow copy of a list then list2=list1.copy() will do what you want. If you do that, the IDs of list1 and list2 will differ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, assignment never copies data. You just get a new name that references the same value.

There are basically three cases:

Assignment: just a new name that points to the same object.

`copy.copy` the object itself is copied, but members of the object are not. So a shallow copy of a list will be a new list, have a new ID but will point to the same objects in memory for its elements as the original list.

`copy.deepcopy` recursively copies everything.

Good resources:
http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Ned Batchelder, Facts and myths about python names and values https://youtu.be/_AEJHKGk9ns